# How to add UIBarButtonItem to replace UINavigationBar title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar, xib

I was trying to replace title on `UINavigationController` with `UIButton` via storyboard. but I can't drag `UIButton` to the center of `UINavigationBar`.

I tried to made `UIButton` programmatically and then assign to the `title` property, but it shows a warning:

```
incompatible pointer type assigning to "NSString *" from "UIButton *"
```

are there any solutions to implement that?

I'm sorry for my bad english, I'm not native.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a titleView to your navigation item, then you can add any subviews you want including your button. So just drag a UIView into the navigation item first, then your button.